# Loading Galleria galleries on click with JSON data. I need fresh eyes to see my mistakes

Tags: xml, json, jquery, galleria

My script can be broken down into three parts:

1. Event handlers to capture the id of the clicked menu item. This is the gallery name that tells the script where to find a particular gallery's images and xml file.
2. A function to extract the image info from the xml and convert it to usable JSON.
3. Loading the JSON into Galleria.

Either the JSON isn't making it into Galleria, or I am not loading it correctly. Unfortunately, I'm way too new to JS to be very effective at debugging this. I feel like I'm in pretty deep water with this one.

The site is at http://willowbrook.businesscatalyst.com/showcase.

Here is my script. I'm using the latest jQuery and the xml2json plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var firstGallery            = 'kitchens';
var galleriaNavID           = '#showcasenav';
var galleriaID          = '#showcaseitems';
var selectedClass           = 'selected';
var imageFolder         = '/images/showcase/'; // Don't forget the / (forward slash) before and after
var xmlFileName         = 'PhotoGallery.xml';
var selectedNavElement  = galleriaNavID+' .'+selectedClass;
var galleryName         = $(selectedNavElement).attr('id');

if(galleryName == null) {
    galleryName = firstGallery;
    $('#'+firstGallery).click();
};

function loadGalleria() {
    function GalleriaBCtoJson() {   // Convert PhotoGallery XML to JSON and load dynamically into Galleria

        var data = new Array;

        $.get(imageFolder+galleryName+'/'+xmlFileName, function(xml){
            var i;
            var imgArray = $.xml2json(xml).album.img;
            for(i in imgArray) { 
                data.push({ image: imageFolder+galleryName+'/'+imgArray[i].src });
            };
        });
        return data;
    };

    var data = GalleriaBCtoJson();

    if ($(galleriaID).data('galleria')) { // If Galleria has already been initialized,
        $(galleriaID).data('galleria').load( data ); // load galleria with the new data
    }
    else {  // Call Galleria, set options,
        $(galleriaID).galleria({    
            dataSource: data,   // and add the data as dataSource
            image_crop: true,
            carousel: true,
            carousel_speed: 2000,
            autoplay: 5000,
            thumbnails: true,
            showInfo: false,
            transition: 'fade',
            transition_speed: 600,
            lightbox: true,
            easing: 'galleriaIn',
            pauseOnInteraction: false,
            debug: false
        });
    }
};


$(galleriaNavID+' a').click(function(e) { // attach event handler to the menu
    e.preventDefault();

    $(selectedNavElement).removeClass(selectedClass); // toggle selected class
    $(this).addClass(selectedClass);

    galleryName = $(this).attr('id');
    loadGalleria();
});
```

});

Here is my finished solution using the advice. This works perfectly:

```
            galleria : function(){
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var firstGallery        = 'kitchens';
                var galleriaNavID       = '#showcasenav';
                var galleriaID          = '#showcaseitems';
                var selectedClass       = 'selected';
                var imageFolder         = '/images/showcase/';  // Don't forget the / (forward slash) before and after
                var xmlFileName         = 'PhotoGallery.xml';
                var selectedNavElement  = galleriaNavID+' .'+selectedClass;
                var galleryName         = $(selectedNavElement).attr('id');

                if(galleryName == null) {
                    galleryName = firstGallery;
                };

                function loadGalleria() {
                    function GalleriaBCtoJson(callback) {   // Convert PhotoGallery XML to JSON and load dynamically into Galleria

                        var data = [];

                        $.get(imageFolder+galleryName+'/'+xmlFileName, function(xml){
                            var i;
                            var imgArray = $.xml2json(xml).album.img;
                            for(i in imgArray) { 
                                data.push({ image: imageFolder+galleryName+'/'+imgArray[i].src });
                            };
                            callback(data);
                        });
                    };

                    var data = GalleriaBCtoJson(function(data) {
                        if ($(galleriaID).data('galleria')) {   // If Galleria has already been initialized,
                            $(galleriaID).data('galleria').load( data );    // load galleria with the new data
                        }
                        else {  // Call Galleria, set options,
                            $(galleriaID).galleria({    
                                dataSource: data,   // and add the data as dataSource
                                image_crop: true,
                                carousel: true,
                                carousel_speed: 2000,
                                autoplay: 5000,
                                thumbnails: true,
                                showInfo: false,
                                transition: 'fade',
                                transition_speed: 600,
                                lightbox: true,
                                easing: 'galleriaIn',
                                pauseOnInteraction: false,
                                debug: false
                            });
                        }
                    });
                };


                $(galleriaNavID+' a').click(function(e) {   // attach event handler to the menu
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $(selectedNavElement).removeClass(selectedClass);   // toggle selected class
                    $(this).addClass(selectedClass);

                    galleryName = $(this).attr('id');
                    loadGalleria();
                });

                $('#'+firstGallery).click();
            });
        }
```

Just remember to put the xml2json and galleria plugins in the head. They can be found at: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/#tab-Download

and http://galleria.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure *exactly* what the problem is, but when you do:

```
var data = GalleriaBCtoJson();
```

...you will get an empty array, because the `$.get` callback has not yet been called. The function returns `data` but since it is returned before the ajax is complete, it’s empty. You can confirm this with a simple console.

You need to do something like:

```
GalleriaBCtoJson(function(data) {
    // continue using data
});
```

And the `GalleriaBCtoJson`:

```
function GalleriaBCtoJson(callback) {
    var data = [];
    $.get(url, function(xml){
        // loop and insert into data here
        callback(data);
    });
 }
```

Comment: So would you suggest putting my if/else inside the function call (where you put "// continue using data")? I guess I don't understand how the ajax isn't complete by the time it is assigned to the data variable.

Comment: @AdamCook Yes, something like that. When you return `data`, it is empty. The `data.push()` population is done after the return is made, so you need to call another function after the population has finished instead of returning data from the function, a so called *callback*. This is typical for asynchronous programming, and you might as well get your head around it now if you aim to program JavaScript in the future.